# Splitting MySQL Table for Better Performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance

i'm working on a little application, and I'm using MySQL database to hold the data related to the application.

That's what makes me wonder:

I have a lot of books (100, for example), Inside of each book there are thousands of photos (about 30,000 average).
I want to hold the information about each photo in my database, and obviously, I want to know from which book the photo was taken.

I'm wondering how to design my database, to make it as efficient as possible.
I was thinking about two options of holding the info:

(the obvious)

1. Creating 2 tables:
   a. A table which hold the whole photos (from all of the books) (photoID, ...... , bookID)
   b. A table which will hold the books. (bookID, bookName)

   - bookID is a foreign key references to the books table, bookID.

(the idea which I'm not sure about)

1. Creating 100 tables, each of them will hold the exactly the same fields.

I read some articles which saying that MySQL created for holding millions of rows, but I found a lot of threads of people complaining about slow reading from the DB.

In my app I'm going to deal with about 3 million rows, which method should I use for better performance? maybe another way I didn't think about?

thank you!

Comment: Think twice before creating 100 tables.  Do you really want to manage that?  Three million rows is nothing.  Go with the first approach and if necessary (after you look at performance) shard the tables along something natural (last name of author book, or first name, or title of book, etc... whatever gives you a decent distribution).

Comment: I think that your answer, combined with the answer below helped me to decide, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all think about future management, Is no of books constant over duration?
are there any chances of growing no of books? if answer is yes then you will have to create new tables for them and manage them.

Though its not a big task but it makes it difficult to manage. first approach is good for 3 million (which is not a big no. from DB perspective. I have managed ~1 billion rows in a single table with acceptable performance)

With proper indexing and DB tunning (buffer pool,prefetch size,cache,procedures etc.) you can get acceptable performance.

One more thing I would like to suggest for optimization in your case, Try compressing images which you are storing in DB. There are many lossless compression algo(image quality remains intact) which will give compression upto 90% (reduce size by 90%). This will be helpful when you retrieve the data.

Comment: About your suggestion - I was thinking about storing those images in a file system, while saving a link to them in the db, again, considering performence. 
which way is better?

Comment: that is again a very big question whose answer depends on your application,environment, type of queries on DB etc. for easyness and maintainability DB is good choice but make sure you dont run aggregations/order by/sub sql queries and you dont have frequent updates else you will be in stone age for perf. in those cases FS is better option.

Comment: @Reuven Chacha Ask yourself. If you add images to the DB you need Apache, PHP and MySQL to display the image (depending on your used softwares). If you add the images to the file system you only need Apache. So which one will be faster?